# Oracle SQL Transforming sql rows into columns grouping by another column

Tags: sql, oracle, rows, col

I am facing trouble designing SQL for the below scenario.

My table structure looks like this

TABLE IMSK

```
id | key | value | group_id
1  | k1  | a1    | g1
2  | k2  | a2    | g1
3  | k3  | a3    | g1
4  | k1  | b1    | g2
5  | k2  | b2    | g2
6  | k3  | b3    | g2
```

As you can see, I store 3 keys for every group id. Values will be different for each group_id. I need to show this information in a report in the following manner.

```
k1 | k2 | k3
a1 | a2 | a3
b1 | b2 | b3
```

Keys will become the column headers and every row will correspond to a group_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select group_id,
       max(case when key = 'k1' then value end) as key1,
       max(case when key = 'k2' then value end) as key2,
       max(case when key = 'k3' then value end) as key3
from imsk
group by group_id;
```

Comment: one more question. I will have other keys also (k4, k5) in other rows against different group_ids but I do not need those in the result. Currently I am getting also  those rows with null values in k1, k2, k3 columns. I tried adding a (where key1 is not null) but got an error saying key1 is an invalid identifier

Comment: @siddhant . . . add `where key in ('k1', 'k2', 'k3')` before the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e764a/7)

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
SELECT KEY, VALUE FROM TABLE1)
SELECT * FROM  CTE1
PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR KEY IN ('k1', 'k2', 'k3'))
UNION
SELECT * FROM  CTE1
PIVOT (MIN(VALUE) FOR KEY IN ('k1', 'k2', 'k3'));
```